# FFT using OpenCV gives two matrices?

Tags: python, opencv, fft

I am using numpy FFT to compute the spectrum from the input matrix. My sample input is a 2D matrix

```
A=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9]]
```

My python code is

```
FFT= np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(A))
```

Output

[image]

Now, I am trying to use the dft2 function of Opencv. I get the outputs similar to python. But I am getting matrices with real and imaginary outputs in different dimensions

[image]

I am looking to get a matrix having real and imaginary parts together in one dimension like python. My code using OpenCV

```
dft=cv2.dft(np.float64(A),flags =  cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT|cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
```

How I can get similar results using OpenCV in python. Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "one matrix having both real and imaginary parts together"? The result _is_ a single matrix, just a 3-dimensional one.

Comment: I want the output in one dimension .. Like the one I am getting in Python

Comment: Have modified my question

Comment: Also, do you want the result from OpenCV to be identical to that from numpy? Or should it `dft_shift` keep the size it currently has?

Comment: I want result to be identical to numpy ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
A=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9]]
dft=cv2.dft(np.float64(A),flags =  cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_csv=dft[...,0]+1j*dft[...,1]
dft_np = np.fft.fft2(A)
assert (dft_np==dft_csv).all()
print(dft_np)
print(dft_csv)
```

output is:

```
[[ 40.+0.j  -4.+4.j  -4.+0.j  -4.-4.j]
 [-20.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j]]
[[ 40.+0.j  -4.+4.j  -4.+0.j  -4.-4.j]
 [-20.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j]]
```

I hope this late answer will help new visitors